# Sum is incorrect when trying to join two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, sum

I'm struggling with getting the correct sum from `qty` column when using joins. The problem occurs when I try to get the `timestamp` from the `paymentType` table and joining these against the `rowid` from `orders` and `paymentType` table and then grouping the `timestamp` on days `(day(from_unixtime(paymentType.timestamp)))`

I want the sum of `qty` by the hour using the `timestamp` in the `paymentType` table, the only link is the `rowid` (this is codeigniter's cart module's `rowid`). The logical problem (at least for me) is that it exists more rows in the `orders` table (as this is per product) than the `paymentType` table (this is just to keep track of whether debit or cash was used). When I join these tables together, the sum for each hour gets multiplied by each hit in `orders.rowid <--> paymentType.rowid`.

I'm sorry if the explanation is bad, but I'm hoping that it's understandable enough that I could get help on this matter.

I have at least 10 queries I've tried, but none seem to work in the way I want.

The following is my `orders` table

```
+---------+----+-------+-----+----------+------------------+----------------------------------+
| orderID | id | price | qty | subtotal |       name       |              rowid               |
+---------+----+-------+-----+----------+------------------+----------------------------------+
|       3 | 49 |    35 |   1 |       35 | Red Bull Stor    | f457c545a9ded88f18ecee47145a72c0 |
|       4 | 24 |    35 |   1 |       35 | Monster Energy   | 1ff1de774005f8da13f42943881c655f |
|       5 | 49 |    35 |   1 |       35 | Red Bull Stor    | f457c545a9ded88f18ecee47145a72c0 |
|       6 | 19 |    20 |   1 |       20 | Sprite 0.5L      | 1f0e3dad99908345f7439f8ffabdffc4 |
|       7 |  1 |    25 |   1 |       25 | Pringles         | c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b |
|       8 | 43 |    20 |   1 |       20 | Lån av stekovn   | 17e62166fc8586dfa4d1bc0e1742c08b |
|       9 | 46 |    35 |   1 |       35 | Burn             | d9d4f495e875a2e075a1a4a6e1b9770f |
|      10 | 49 |    35 |   3 |      105 | Red Bull Stor    | f457c545a9ded88f18ecee47145a72c0 |
|      11 | 49 |    35 |   1 |       35 | Red Bull Stor    | f457c545a9ded88f18ecee47145a72c0 |
|      12 | 29 |    25 |   1 |       25 | Potetskruer      | 6ea9ab1baa0efb9e19094440c317e21b |
|      13 | 16 |    20 |   1 |       20 | Coca-Cola 0.5L   | c74d97b01eae257e44aa9d5bade97baf |
|      14 | 46 |    35 |   1 |       35 | Burn             | d9d4f495e875a2e075a1a4a6e1b9770f |
|      15 |  1 |    25 |   1 |       25 | Pringles         | c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b |
|      16 | 18 |    20 |   1 |       20 | Eventyrbrus 0.5L | 6f4922f45568161a8cdf4ad2299f6d23 |
|      17 | 16 |    20 |   1 |       20 | Coca-Cola 0.5L   | c74d97b01eae257e44aa9d5bade97baf |
|      18 | 15 |    30 |   1 |       30 | Coca-Cola 1.5L   | 9bf31c7ff062936a96d3c8bd1f8f2ff3 |
|      19 | 19 |    20 |   1 |       20 | Sprite 0.5L      | 1f0e3dad99908345f7439f8ffabdffc4 |
|      20 | 50 |    20 |   1 |       20 | Stratos bar      | c0c7c76d30bd3dcaefc96f40275bdc0a |
+---------+----+-------+-----+----------+------------------+----------------------------------+
```

This is the `paymentType` table

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+----------------------------------+
| paymentID | paymentType | timestamp  |              rowid               |
+-----------+-------------+------------+----------------------------------+
|         3 | Kort        | 1424447799 | f457c545a9ded88f18ecee47145a72c0 |
|         4 | Kort        | 1424448791 | 1ff1de774005f8da13f42943881c655f |
|         5 | Kort        | 1424452822 | f457c545a9ded88f18ecee47145a72c0 |
|         6 | Kort        | 1424454483 | c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b |
|         7 | Kort        | 1424454665 | d9d4f495e875a2e075a1a4a6e1b9770f |
|         8 | Kontant     | 1424454799 | f457c545a9ded88f18ecee47145a72c0 |
|         9 | Kontant     | 1424454825 | f457c545a9ded88f18ecee47145a72c0 |
|        10 | Kort        | 1424454870 | 6ea9ab1baa0efb9e19094440c317e21b |
|        11 | Kontant     | 1424455510 | d9d4f495e875a2e075a1a4a6e1b9770f |
|        12 | Kort        | 1424455847 | c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b |
|        13 | Kontant     | 1424456025 | 6f4922f45568161a8cdf4ad2299f6d23 |
|        14 | Kontant     | 1424456099 | c74d97b01eae257e44aa9d5bade97baf |
|        15 | Kontant     | 1424456148 | 9bf31c7ff062936a96d3c8bd1f8f2ff3 |
|        16 | Kontant     | 1424456242 | c0c7c76d30bd3dcaefc96f40275bdc0a |
|        17 | Kort        | 1424456266 | c74d97b01eae257e44aa9d5bade97baf |
|        18 | Kort        | 1424456445 | c0c7c76d30bd3dcaefc96f40275bdc0a |
|        19 | Kort        | 1424456964 | 70efdf2ec9b086079795c442636b55fb |
|        20 | Kort        | 1424457701 | 1ff1de774005f8da13f42943881c655f |
+-----------+-------------+------------+----------------------------------+
```

**EDIT:**
SQL Queries I've tried so far, there exists more, but these are the latest. I would think these are the most "correct".

```
select orders.rowid, concat(convert(paymentType.timestamp,CHAR(11))) timestamp, orders.qty, orders.name
from orders
join paymentType
on orders.rowid = paymentType.rowid
order by paymentType.timestamp;

select orders.rowid, hour(from_unixtime(concat(convert(paymentType.timestamp,CHAR(11))))), orders.qty, orders.name
from orders
join paymentType
on orders.rowid = paymentType.rowid
#where orders.name = '".stripslashes($name)."'
order by paymentType.timestamp
;
select orders.qty, orders.name, orders.rowid, paymentType.rowid, paymentType.timestamp
from orders, paymentType
where orders.rowid = paymentType.rowid;

select qty, name, hour(from_unixtime(timestamp)) hour, day(from_unixtime(timestamp)) day
from orders_w_time
where name = 'Red Bull Stor'
;

select sum(qty) from orders
inner join (select distinct rowid from paymentType) pt
on orders.rowid = pt.rowid
where orders.name = 'Pølse';

select sum(orders.qty) totalqty, orders.name, pt.timestamp timestamp from orders ord
inner join (select timestamp from paymentType where paymentType.rowid = ord.rowid) pt
on orders.rowid = pt.rowid
where orders.name = 'Red Bull Stor';
select * from
(
select rowid, timestamp from paymentType
group by hour(from_unixtime(timestamp))
) pt
left join
(
select sum(qty), name, rowid from orders
) ord
on ord.rowid = pt.rowid
;
Select
  paymentType.rowid,
  orders.name,
  orders.qty,
  paymentType.timestamp
From
  orders,
  paymentType
Group By
  day(from_unixtime(paymentType.timestamp));

select sum(orders.qty) Total
from orders
left join
(
select rowid,timestamp
from paymentType
) as paymet on orders.rowid = paymet.rowid
group by day(from_unixtime(paymet.timestamp))
;

select paymentType.rowid, ord.qty, timestamp
from paymentType
left join
(
select orders.rowid, qty
from orders
) as ord on ord.rowid = paymentType.rowid
;
```

The intended result is to sum the qty column for 'Red Bull Stor' (ie.) for the each day grouped by the hour.

Comment: This would be a great question if you provided a couple of the queries that got you the closest to your answer.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Well, it would be adequate. A great question would provide proper DDLs and a desired result set.

Comment: @Strawberry: Fair enough. It's at least on the right track for someone's second post :)

Comment: @Cory I've updated the original question with the lastest MySQL queries I've tried so far. If there is a need for me to mock up som examples for the expected result set I will try based on the queries I got so far.@Strawberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
select o.name
     , pt.rowid
     , sum(o.qty)
     , hour(from_unixtime(pt.timestamp))
     , day(from_unixtime(pt.timestamp))
from orders o
join paymentType pt using(rowid)
where o.name = 'Red Bull Stor'
group by o.name
       , o.rowid
       , hour(from_unixtime(pt.timestamp))
       , day(from_unixtime(pt.timestamp));
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9773c/1)

Comment: Thank you @notulysses! - The dataset that I have is unfortunately not complete, and as I have figured out the there was a multitude of queries that I've tried that actually works as intended (giving me the correct result), but since the data in my tables isn't nowhere near being complete I just cannot produce the results I want. (And btw, rowid in codeigniter, is an identifier for product, not cart or order.... This was the main cause for my difficulties in producing the right set of data) Thanks again for all help, your query works exactly as i want :-)